# Not able to use filterbar fields for searching

Tags: sapui5

I am using below code for filtering data in Value search help with three input group items as below, but I am not able to get the data which is given in those three fields to do filtering.

```
        var oFilterBar = new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar({
        advancedMode:  true,
        filterBarExpanded: true,
        showGoOnFB: !sap.ui.Device.system.phone,
        filterGroupItems: [new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterGroupItem({ groupTitle: "foo", groupName: "gn1", name: "n1", label: "Orderid", control: new sap.m.Input()}),
                           new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterGroupItem({ groupTitle: "foo", groupName: "gn1", name: "n2", label: "OrderType", control: new sap.m.Input()}),
                           new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterGroupItem({ groupTitle: "foo", groupName: "gn1", name: "n3", label: "Planplant", control: new sap.m.Input()})],

    search: function() {
            // var iOrder = sap.ui.getCore().byId("oFilterBar");
            // sap.m.MessageToast.show("Search pressed '");
                        oTable.bindRows({path: "/OrderDataSet", filters:  [
    new sap.ui.model.Filter( "Orderid",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, iOrder )]
    // new sap.ui.model.Filter("Planplant",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, iPlan ),
    // new sap.ui.model.Filter("Description",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, iDes)] 
      } );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a diferent case but, can help to get what you want

```
search : function(oEvent) {
            var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
            var oBarContent = oSource.getContent();
            var oToolBarContent = oBarContent[0].getContent();
            var oSearch = oToolBarContent[1];
            var sValue = oSearch.getValue();
```